# Drupal : How can get all node post in this year by SQL

Tags: sql

I need to query the database directly using php. I need to limit my query to nodes created in the current year. I know that the node table contains the date the node was created in the 'created' column and that this contains a date as a timestamp.

I am not sure how to get the current year and express it as a range of timestamps and return only nodes that were created between the two timestamps.

Comment: Which DBMS you are using?

Comment: @DirkNM its Drupal CMS

Comment: I want to know underlying database system. MySQL, Postgres or something like that.

Comment: @DirkNM Drupal use mysql